# Difference in 2 worksheets. Office 365 MAC

Tags: excel, compare

Some back-end info. 
So I had a server crash. But luckily before it happened I was able to export a list to Excel of the folder and file structure. My technical team was able to restore a huge chuck of information. 
I have now exported the same list (After recovery) to another spreadsheet. 
How do I run a compare between the 2 files to see what was not recovered. This is for Office 365 Mac. Running High Sierra.
Both files have 3 columns.

[New data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCG4d.png)
[Old data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTeUb.png)

Thank you kindly in advance.

edited - screenshots added as per feedback

Comment: This is a job of a list processing system, not a spreadsheet. You'd be better off exporting your Excel data of the folder/file structure to something that can handle that list more effectively (like python, perl, etc.) or just use it to recreate the filestructure (with empty files or symbolic links to the restored files or whatever) and then use shell tools to sync/merge/list differences.

Comment: That said, if you must use Excel, then edit your question to show the three columns of each file and exactly what you want to do with them (how you want to process them).

Comment: Thank you for that. Yeah Excel is my tool as my knowledge of Python or Perl is about as vast as my knowledge on Nuclear Physics....
I will edit that now. Thanks again. Any feedback is appreciated

Comment: Putting actual formatted text in your question is much preferred over screen shots. But it looks like you just have a list of files, with no folder info. In that case, it would be pretty easy to find missing or out-of-sync entries with vlookup to look up the filename (column A) in the new data dataset. If it exists, use vlookup to pull the date and compare it with the old data's date, and process accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In old data, column D:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,'New Data'!A:C,3,)),"Missing",IF(VLOOKUP(A2,'New Data'!A:C,3,)=C2,"OK","Out of sync"))
```

(formula shown for row 2; copy that down the entire column)

This shows "OK" if the file exists in New Data with the same date, "missing" if it isn't in New Data, and "Out of sync" if it's there but the date is different.

You can do something similar with the size comparison if need be.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I am so rusty with my Excel. Will test that this evening and revert. Sir, you rock.